# Printing columns in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cut

I am having a little problem with my script. I have a text file with several columns and what I want to do is print the last one (12th one) as a first one and then print columns no. 7, 8 and 9. I am able to print out columns 7, 8 and 9 with command:

```
awk -v f=7 -v t=9 '{for(i=f;i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s",$i,(i==t)?"\n":OFS)}' $file
```

where the $1 is the parameter for the file path

Any ideas how can I solve my little problem?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got a file like:

```
bash-3.2$ cat myfile
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
a b c d e f g h i j  k  l
```

Then  simply

```
bash-3.2$ awk '{print $NF, $7, $8, $9}' myfile
12 7 8 9
l g h i
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I am pretty much new to scripting. Your answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $NF, $7, $8, $9}'
```

will print last one followed by 7 8 and 9

Comment: @fedorqui sorry for that. failed to double check my output . Removed from answer